# i need help about the high-res icon on android market, i really can't get the hang of it

Tags: android, android-widget, google-play, android-icons

so i just uploaded my app on the market, everything is working fine, my only problem is the high res icon is not appearing, but I've done all the req. its 512x512px 32bit I've tried uploading in jpg or png, its less than 1024kb the only things i didn't do is the alpha thingy since i am not knowledgeable in any graphics tool but i use paint.net for re-sizing and simple effects but i really don't know how to do this alpha thingy, so if anyone can just dumb it down for me.. i would really be thankful, btw i researched about the alpha thing and there is just different alpha terms out there in Google and i really don't know what specific alpha or what is alpha for that matter, if any of you have already successfully uploaded an app on the market with the high res icon working please just teach how you did it, i'll really be thankful..

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: ^ try this or just wait a few hours. the market is sometimes slow / functions strangely. a few weeks ago there was a problem with some apps showing duplicate screenshots.

Comment: Download gimp, then take your icon and resize it using Image > scale Image. Then make it look how you want to, then right click on it, click Image, then Mode, then Indexed. Save it as an indexed image. Then try uploading. If that fails try saving it in RGB mode instead. I think this will work, anyway. But I used Photoshop for the only app I've uploaded so far. Not sure how I did it with that.

Comment: @jakar so i don't really have to do the alpha thing? i'll try using gimp ang following your instructions first...

Comment: thank you to all i now have some ideas...

Comment: When I uploaded my app, I didn't do anything with the alpha, but i'm not too sure. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i uploaded an appp before and the same is happened, open it after while or open it from your mobile and you will find the icon.

it is cause cashing issue or maybe google need time to process image.

Answer (score -1):

if you see "Store Listing". down. down.. down... there is another input box

I also wasted very much time. But, the solution was very, very, simple.

there is another input box.